# Python pandas: concat two DataFrames with different number of rows by duplication

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, namely `df`, like:

```
    Name  Subject Score
0    Tom        A    91
1    Bob        B    92
2    Ali        C    93
```

and a dictionary like:

```
exam_info = {
    "exam_date": "2021-04-01",
    "advisor":   "Jim",
}
```

My goal DataFrame is to insert `exam_date` and `advisor` into each row of `df`, resulting like:

```
      exam_date advisor Name  Subject Score
0    2021-04-01     Jim  Tom        A    91
1    2021-04-01     Jim  Bob        B    92
2    2021-04-01     Jim  Ali        C    93
```

I know following code can be working:

```
df.insert(0, 'advisor', exam_info['advisor'])
df.insert(0, 'exam_date', exam_info['exam_date'])
```

but in the real project, I have a number of `df`s to `insert` and the real `exam_info` dictionary is also quite lengthy, thus there will be a bunch of blocks of `df.insert(..)` in the code, which is not so elegant.

I also tried to change `exam_info` into a helper DataFrame `df_helper` like:

```
    exam_date   advisor
0  2021-04-01       Jim
```

and then use `pd.concat([df_helper, df], axis=1)`, but the resulting DataFrame will only have `exam_date` and `advisor` in the first row, with the corresponding columns in other rows are all `Nan`, like:

```
      exam_date advisor Name  Subject Score
0    2021-04-01     Jim  Tom        A    91
1           NaN     NaN  Bob        B    92
2           NaN     NaN  Ali        C    93
```

Please advice if any more elegant ways to concat both DataFrames so that the `NaN`s are filled up with correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([xam_info])],axis=1).fillna(method='ffill')
```